# How to enforce API calls are coming from authorized site

Tags: php

What is it that I need to do (what request parameter) do I need to check to make sure that someone calling my API is indeed the domain associated with that key, and that they key isn't being used on multiple domains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) with the 'REMOTE_ADDR' or 'REMOTE_HOST'

```
$ip   = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$host = $_SERVER['REMOTE_HOST'];
```

Comment: I believe that those can only be faked if the attacker can intercept the network between the web server and an authorized client, or between the web server and its DNS server.